# Azure server which executes APIM Test

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I have a URL which is only accessible to internal network. Due to certain business requirement, this URL has to be accessible from Azure APIM. The way I call the endpoint is as per screenshot below which I got  from Microsoft docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/mock-api-responses

[image]

However, I got the following error message because myprivatedomain.com is only accessible from internal VPN. May I know how APIM execute the test API? (ie, what's the IP address? ,etc..) Thanks.

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

```
content-length: 85

content-type: application/json

vary: Origin

{
    "error": "The remote name could not be resolved: 'myprivatedomain.com'"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When API Management deploys in internal virtual network mode, all the service endpoints  are only visible within a virtual network that you control the access to. None of the service endpoints are registered on the public DNS server.

1. Enable a virtual network connection using the Azure portal

[image]

2.Enable a virtual network connection by using [PowerShell cmdlets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.apimanagement/update-azapimanagementregion?view=azps-4.7.0)

```
Update-AzApiManagementRegion
      -ApiManagement <PsApiManagement>
      -Location <String>
      -Sku <PsApiManagementSku>
      -Capacity <Int32>
      [-VirtualNetwork <PsApiManagementVirtualNetwork>]
      [-DefaultProfile <IAzureContextContainer>]
      [<CommonParameters>]
```

3.For internal virtual network mode, you have to manage your own DNS.
You can set up custom domain names for all your service endpoints as shown in the following image:

[image]

Then you can create records in your DNS server to access the endpoints that are only accessible from within your virtual network.

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-using-with-internal-vnet).

Comment: thx joey cai. I will  have a talk with our azure admin. if it works, I will upvote the answer.